# What is the relationship between SL(n) and SO(n)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm in Linear Algebra right now and we're mostly just working with vector spaces, but they're introducing us to the basic concepts of fields and groups in preparation taking for Abstract Algebra later on.

Let us assume the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$. I know that $SL(n)$ is the group of all $n\times n$ matrices that are both invertible and have a determinant of $1$. I also understand that $SO(n)$ is the group of all $n\times n$ orthogonal matrices that have a determinant of $1$. But what is the relationship between the two groups? I think that $SO(n) \subset SL(n)$ but also $SO(n) \neq SL(n)$, since there are probably matrices in $SL(n)$ that are not orthogonal?

Comment: That's right. $SO(n)$ is a subgroup of $SL(n)$, and for $n > 1$, it is a proper subgroup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, because every matrix in $SO(n)$ has determinant one, $SO(n)\subset SL(n)$. There are also matrices in $SL(n)$ which are not orthogonal; for example, upper triangular matrices whose diagonals multiply to $1$ have unit determinant but are not symmetric.

There are deeper relationships, though. The group $SL(n)$ has an [Iwasawa decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_decomposition), a way of writing any matrix in $SL(n)$ as a product of three simpler matrices:
$$ \bigg( \mbox{orthogonal}\bigg) \bigg( \mbox{diagonal}\bigg) \bigg( \mbox{upper triangular}\bigg).$$
One consequence is that, as a *space* rather than as a *group*, $SL(n)$ is the product $SO(n)\times \mathbb{R}^k$ (for some dimension $k$). The group $SO(n)$ is called a "maximal compact subgroup."

Answer (score 2):

To add some intuition to this, for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $SL(n)$ is the space of all the transformations with determinant $1$, or in other words, all transformations that keep the volume constant. This is because the determinant is what one multiplies within the integral to get the volume in the transformed space.

$SO(n)$ is the subset in which the transformation is orthogonal ($R^T R = I$). Such matrices leave the angle between two vectors as well as their length unchanged, since under $R\in SO(n)$:

$$a^T \cdot b\rightarrow a^T R^T \cdot R b = a^T \cdot b$$

We typically call such transformations rotations, and they indeed conserve the volume. However, one can create transformations that conserve volume but are not rotations - as pointed out, a diagonal matrix with determinant $1$ will stretch some axes and shrink others (e.g. turn a sphere into an ellipse), but will do so while conserving the overall volume.

Comment: 9 years later and what a coincidence, I was just studying statistics and revisited orthogonal transformations in the proof of Cochran’s Theorem!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. For example, $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\in SL(2)$ but not in $SO(2)$.